# CSV Parse: search a value in a certain column and print out the whole row that contains it

Tags: ruby, csv

So, I already made a similar question a few days back that got me very close to figuring it out. I wanted a system that'd take the user input and search it through an specific column and, when found, would print the entire row the column was in. I already defined the method that'll search through the .csv, however, it's still not working as intended. The exact error is:

```
undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I've viewed and reviewed the .csv, tried out solutions that I found for the same problem, but none seem to work.

My `data.csv` looks like this:

```
Name;Age;Gender
Edward;21;Male
Michael;21;a
Sarah;22;a
```

As you can see, I use "`a`" so that I don't use a blank space.

Also, I used `:col_sep => ";"` in the code to avoid further errors (it's too big to change every semicolon into a comma manually).

I really don't know what else to do at this point, I understand the problem, but I can't find the solution.

This is what my code looks like:

```
require 'csv'

def find_row_in_csv(file_path, column_name, search_value)
  CSV.foreach(file_path, headers: true, :row_sep => "\r\n", :col_sep => ";").find do |row|
    row[column_name].include?(search_value)
  end
end

search_value = gets.chomp.to_s

matching_row = find_row_in_csv('data.csv', "Name", search_value)
p matching_row
```

I used that `:row_sep => "\r\n"` because I was getting a malformed CSV error, but now that I fixed that, it appears as though I haven't defined the `include?` method for NilClass (NoMethodError), which I don't understand since there's no blank values in the .csv.

I thought it'd work as is, since I pretty much copied it from the best response I got, but I've been stuck with this for a few days now.

Comment: After removing `:row_sep => "\r\n",` your code works fine for me: `find_row_in_csv('data.csv', 'Age', '22')
 #=> #<CSV::Row "Name":"Sarah" "Age":"22" "Gender":"a">`. Ruby should be able to figure out what the row separator is on your system.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for the help!, however, I'm still getting the same error: ``main.rb:15:in `block in find_row_in_csv': undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)``

Comment: As I expect you know, the error message is telling you that `row[column_name] #=> nil`. Try inserting the following line above the line containing `row[column_name]`: `puts "row=#{row}, column_name=#{column_name}"` and report back what is displayed.

Comment: @CarySwoveland As it turns out, you were right all along, there was no problem with my code. The problem was my compiler. I uninstalled it and installed it again and the code ran perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad to hear to solved the problem.